# neural network AR opinion and math background

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, autoregressive

I'm trying to predict a time series using the neural network approach. I saw this function "nnetar", in the "forecast" package, what do you think? I can not find a mathematical explanation about it. Can you suggest where I can find it?

Comment: Did you look at the vignette in the `forecast`package?

Comment: sure but the mathematical explanation is not enough, 
I found this paper, can it be suitable for the nnetar package? "time series forecasting with neural networks: a comparative study using the airline data (julian faraway 1998)"

Comment: That paper is 20+ years old at this point, and very out of date due in large part to advances in NN design.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Hyndman, the author of the forecast package, gives a brief explanation of NNETAR in his online book:

https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/3